# KDevelop: How to disable source-code tool tips

Tags: kdevelop

I'm using Kdevelop 5.1.2 on Kubuntu 17.10.

When I move the mouse pointer in the editor to a line of code, there constantly appear huge tool-tips with info I usually do not want to see, hiding the code and making it difficult to move the mouse pointer to the intended code position.

Especially annoying is that when there is a compile error in the line the tool tip will not disappear when I move the mouse pointer away.

Is there a way to switch off this behaviour, i.e. so that no tool tips appear, or at least the delay can be increased?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to turn off only the tooltips.
You could either:

1. Go to settings->plugins and uncheck the "code browser".
2. Open the "code browser" panel and reduce it to minimum dimensions, this way the tooltip content will appear inside the panel, not in the editor.

Comment: Actually, disabling corebrowser is the thing to do. it stops showing annoying tooltips.