# How to customize Code Browser of KDevelop?

Tags: kdevelop

I use KDevelop 5.5.0. I like the information that the Code Browser plugin provides, but don't like its behavior. I want it to show the tooltips only when I want them, for example only if the shift key is pressed. At the moment, as I move the mouse cursor around it throws unwanted tooltips, which is so annoying that I prefer to diable it if no customization is possible.

I'm not the only person who finds its behavior annoying (see, for example, [KDevelop: How to disable source-code tool tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297214/kdevelop-how-to-disable-source-code-tool-tips))

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question you link to. The answer given still applies -- if the Code Browser view is visible it replaces the tooltip, otherwise you can disable the plugin altogether.

Comment: @FLHerne, That question asks how to disable it, not how to customize it.

Comment: The question includes customization: "...or at least the delay can be increased?". Anyway, there is no such setting.